# How to Create multiple sequence alignments with fasta files rather then strings of protein sequences in biopython

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta, sequence-alignment

I want to be able to write a multiple sequence alignments using files I have downloaded in the same directory as my script. However in the Biopython Cookbook, the only way this is shown is via writing out strings rather then loading files. I would like to be able to do the latter. Here is how the multiple sequence alignment is made in [Chapter 6.2 of The biopython cookbook](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc75)

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
from Bio.Align import MultipleSeqAlignment

align1 = MultipleSeqAlignment([
             SeqRecord(Seq("ACTGCTAGCTAG", generic_dna), id="Alpha"),
             SeqRecord(Seq("ACT-CTAGCTAG", generic_dna), id="Beta"),
             SeqRecord(Seq("ACTGCTAGDTAG", generic_dna), id="Gamma"),
         ])
```

The goal is to use this in order to make a phylum tree out of all the protein sequences.

Answer (score 0):

the example uses three SeqRecord objects that are created using the DNA strings provided. `SeqIO.parse` enables you to read files in e.g. fasta format and return SeqRecord objects for the alignment.

Example:

```py
import os

from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Align import MultipleSeqAlignment

# files needs to be a list containing the filenames
# use e.g.
# files = [f for f in os.listdir() if 'fasta' in f]

records = []
for f in files:
    for record in SeqIO.parse(f, format='fasta'):
        records.append(record)

align1 = MultipleSeqAlignment(records)
```

Alternatively, if you already have sequence files you can concatenate the files into one and then use a tool like [clustal omega](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/msa/clustalo/) in standalone or online mode.